# R convert column of doubles to logical in a tibble

Tags: r, type-conversion, tibble

I have a tibble that has a column of type double, confirmed with type of, containing 0's and 1's. I need to turn these 0's and 1's into true or false

```
my_tibble$column_to_convert <- as.logical(my_tibble$column_to_convert)
```

has not worked. The values still display as NA

Comment: can you try  `floor(my_tibble$column_to_convert)>0`?

Comment: Please add the first few lines of the output of `my_tibble`.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error:

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

Try this:

```
my_tibble$column_to_convert <- as.logical(unlist(my_tibble$column_to_convert))
```